# Short circuit logical or statement, combined with an inline ternary

Tags: javascript, logic, ternary-operator

I understand how short-circuit evaluation works when using the logical or operator in JavaScript, but I've run into what seems to be a weird edge case I don't fully understand.

So, this snippet works the way I would expect:

`const a = 'a' || 'b';`

with `a` having a value of `'a'`.

And of course, this also works the way I would expect:

`const a = false || 'b';`

with `a` having a value of `'b'`.

However, I've run into this weird situation with an expression like this:

`const a = true || true || true ? 'a' : 'b';`

where `a` now has a value of `'a'`. I've tried other combinations, such as:

`const a = true || false || true ? 'a' : 'b';`

and `a` still has a value of `'a'`.

Another thing to try is something like this:

```
const fn = () => true ? 'a' : 'b';
const a = true || fn();
```

and of course `a` has a value of `true`, and `fn` is never called.

What's going on here?

Comment: Order of operations... `true || true || true ? 'a' : 'b'` is equivalent to `(true || true || true) ? 'a' : 'b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) is evaluated from left to right and the first value that evaluates to a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) is returned, or the last one if none of them evaluates to `true`.

In this case, the first `true` trivially evaluates to `true`, thus the whole condition returns `true`:

```
true || true || false
```

As a result, the first expression of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is evaluated, in this case `'a'`:

```
const a = true || true || true ? 'a' : 'b';
```

For this reason, `a` equals `'a'`.

The same logic applies to the other cases you listed.